# Concrete5.7.5.2 How to Alias an html block with another html block in another page

Tags: concrete5

I have a site running in concrete5.7.5.2. All my pages's footer are uning an html block with the same content in it. When i want to edit something in the footer, i have to edit in all the pages's footer. Is there a way i can just update in one html block and it reflect to all other block that aliased to it?

Answer (score 0):

You can make element for the footer so that you can use it any where. you have to edit it only one place and it will reflect every where you used this.

you can visit for alias
http://www.concrete5.org/community/forums/customizing_c5/display-page-alias/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Global Areas` for this. These are areas you can put into every template, view or single page. It will output the same content site wide.

```
$area = new GlobalArea('handle'); // instead of new Area('handle');
$area->display($c);
```

Everywhere you define a `GlobalArea` with the same `handle` it will output the same content. You can also edit it from every instance.